# PayPal recurring payment Return url issue

Tags: php, paypal

I have implemented PayPal recurring payment in a website Built in PHP with custom code and set the Auto Return ON and put the Return URL into my PayPal account.

I am able to create recurring and PayPal get deduct the amount for entire cycle and for first payment it redirects to our return url page but from second payment PayPal get deduct the amount from client but not redirect to Return URL. This is required to update our database table for payment transaction information.

Please have a look of my code below and guide me that how can I redirect on our Return URL from second payment.

[my paypal code form here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZra7.png)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Return url is to show your customers the outcome of their payment. This shouldn't be used to update your database. You should use webhooks or IPN to update your database. Paypal sends a silent response to your web page, that page is not called/opened in browser actually but silently called by paypal to send transaction details. Create a page on your webserver to catch the paypal response and add that page url to silent response configuration into your paypal account.

For more information please look here
[Paypal IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/)